# Persist setTimeout and setInterval across Node.js restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I set quite a few server-side timeouts with setTimeout and setInterval for each connected user that can last for 10-30 seconds. If the Node.js instance restarts in the middle of one of these timeouts, they are obviously all cleared on restart, which can cause some issues for these users. How would I go about persisting these timeouts, or are there any modules that already help with this?

Comment: can't you use node cron for this?

Comment: How so? These are not cron jobs I'm setting up, they are 10-30 second timeouts based on user interactions with the app.

Comment: You could use beanstalkd for that. It can even persist.

Comment: @JamesSimpson Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something similar to Loc Nguyen's suggestion (looks like I forgot to mark it as the answer). This solution has worked very well, and it has been in production since August without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the start times and durations in Redis and restart incomplete timers when your application reloads. Some Redis modules:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-redis

Comment: How would you determine that app going to crash? Or you will update start_time/duration in redis every second?

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeOut` takes delay as parameter, so when setting timeout, capture `currentServerTime + delay` say `serverTriggerTime` and persist this in DB. Then, on restart of server, create the same timer using the `serverTriggerTime`.
Then, `delay = serverTriggerTime - currentServerTime`, use this delay to set new timer.

When setting timer

```
const date = Date.now();
const serverTriggerTime = date + delay; // time in milliseconds
```

On server restart:

```
serverTriggerTime = // retrieve from DB.
newDelay = serverTriggerTime - Date.now();
```

Also, set new timer only if newDelay >= 0, meaning the trigger time has not reached and will happen after newDelay time.