# Any work-around to make javascript set interval or setTimeout keep counting after node.js server restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently building a reminder bot on slack. This bot is based on node.js and consumes a rails api that persists data with PostgreSQL. When a user sets a task, a setTimeout is triggered and sends a reminder message to the user over slack.

However, all running timers are reset when the node.js server restarts.

While searching for a solution, I saw [only one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454587/persist-settimeout-and-setinterval-across-node-js-restarts?rq=1) James asked sometime ago. The best answer provided there was that he use redis.

I've been going through their documentation and see its a nosql storage. I'm not exactly sure how I could use it in this particular case (no details in the question's answer).

Is there any workaround to keep the setInterval/setTimeout timers counting when server restarts? If I must use Redis, how could I logically go about it?

Comment: Since you already have a DB I would persist your timer state there rather than go to the trouble of having another db. Each time you set time out you need to record that in your db along with a timestamp of when you started it. On server startup you need to get all that data and start all your timeouts again. You need the timestamp in order to adjust how long the delay should be.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but it is worth noting that Slack has a `/remind` feature built-in.

Comment: @AaronDufour Thanks for the tip. I looked it up though and it doesn't look like something I'd be able to integrate with my bot. It requires users themselves to do the configurations. Is it a function you've used? Could you unpack further?

Comment: It sounded similar to what you're building, but you haven't included enough details to be sure.  It is very handy if I want to remind myself of something in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with PostgreSQL as well - when a user sets a task, save the "reminder time" in the DB.  So, say it's noon on 2015-8-18, and user with ID 12 want a reminder in an hour to "start task B", you would save

```
user_id: 12
message: "start task B"
reminder_time: "2015-08-18 13:00:00 UTC"
```

When you send out a reminder, delete it from the DB.  When the server restarts, have it load all of the reminder times, calculate how long until the reminder is supposed to happen, and start a new timeout.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. Why I didn't want to do it was because the slack channel is usually opened by a message from the user. Doing that would require me to open a new channel for each user, get the ID, then pass it to the timeout function for each active task of the user. This seems pretty straight forward. However, it is a linear task and since the users could easily rise over 500 in my team, it didn't strike me as the best approach performance-wise.